# Does Genie.jl have complete documention for modern website launch?

Tags: html, css, forms, julia

Genie.jl (Julia Language) package has great reviews and I find it extremely easy to launch a Genie.jl demo webpage.

However, after that begins the seemingly arduous task of finding an easy to use HTML or markup editor to drag-and-drop design the webpage and then to instantiate those webpage fields to Genie.jl connected database elements. Does anyone know of a complete turnkey example, or at least a full stack set of instructions for a simple but useful webpage that has modern design of dropdown menus, etc.?

GOAL: complete example/instructions on Genie.jl for deployment of well designed, modern website that interfaces user from webpage with well-placed content, such as dropdown menus, to simple mySQL database R/W.

QUESTION: Does anyone have a complete of the steps/examples documented to meet the above goal?

If so, I will use them to deploy Genie.jl for a fully developed, modern, with dropdown menus, website hosting application, and will append/post my complete deployment example.

[Others have posted with this same concern on various sites, asking this same question, but no answer anywhere close to being complete, at least from Google search; hopefully the main Julia packages will catchup to the levels of complete documentation found in Python/R/MatLab.]

Comment: OK, let's reopen this question. However adding a sample code (suppose some Genie form handler or maybe your own try to implement MVC with Genie) would make much bigger chance to attract a useful answer.

Comment: Hi @TLJ can you join GenieFramework discord and ask questions here: https://discord.gg/9zyZbD6J7H

A lot more people will be able to help you with what you are trying to achieve. Thanks 

Also, there's a UI framework built on top of Genie i.e. Stipple which has 30+ UI components including things you need like dropdown menus, radios, placeholders, menubars etc

Comment: check the new documentation on genieframework.com/docs. Its being worked very actively :)